# Disable Auto Padding Tables

Tags: html, css

For our research we are creating realistic situations for our users. Since a week or so, our tables are creating auto padding around some TD's.

Example:
https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_Zekur.html

This is the HTML/CSS:

```css
table {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="Tabel_01" width="991" height="1317" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" width="990" height="177">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_01.gif" width="990" height="177" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="177" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" width="20" height="1140">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_02.gif" width="20" height="1140" alt=""></td>
    <td width="282" height="141">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_Zekur_aap.gif" width="282" height="141" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3" width="378" height="703">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_04.gif" width="378" height="703" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="282" height="146">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_Zekur_auto.gif" width="282" height="146" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="5" width="28" height="1140">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_06.gif" width="28" height="1140" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="141" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" width="282" height="999">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_07.gif" width="282" height="999" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="5" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" width="282" height="994">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_08.gif" width="282" height="994" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="557" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" width="47" height="437">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_09.gif" width="47" height="437" alt=""></td>
    <td width="287" height="144">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_Zekur_vrouw.gif" width="287" height="144" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="44" height="437">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_11.gif" width="44" height="437" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="144" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="287" height="293">
      <img src="https://ads.memo2.nl/2018/Zekur/Auto/FB_ZEKUR_12.gif" width="287" height="293" alt=""></td>
    <td>
      <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="293" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see I already hard coded the height and width into the TD's, but these are overruled with some magic padding.

How to solve this?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow - could you put your html and css into your question please, as we cannot identify where your issue lies without being able to see the code for ourselves.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Also please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: CSS is over two decades old. Don't use tables for layout.

Comment: Re edit: Your [mcve] doesn't look very **minimal**

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks for your comments. Of course I'm interested in a new way of programming this easy. At this point it's important for me to create sections in Photoshop and export this to an automatic HTML in which I can use iFrames or in this case moving images. The point on getting it minimal, it will destroy my point. All TD's are padding if I remove other Rows. Hope you can help me out with this, I'm stuck at this point. Also tried to put on Style="padding:0px!important;" and thats not working as well.

Comment: The problem is that the contents of the table cells are not the same height.

Comment: I agree that pixel-constrained tables are not really a good modern layout mechanism however, the provided sample and link to a working page were a good sample of the issue that would have been really hard to reduce further.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell isn't padding, it's expanding to 703 pixels like its direct neighbour.

Here is what your table looks like:

[image: Table layout with vertical sizes]

The yellow cells both expand to 703 pixel height, the same as the green 3x3 cell for some reason. I was trying to see which one was causing the constraints to go crazy and found that if you remove all spacers from the right except the red one of 557 pixels, it was all falling into place. It might be because it's the only row where the spacer is the sole signe rowspan cell.

I only tested on Firefox but I guess that it'll be the same on others.